# PowerShell WPF DataGrid: color selected row green/red and set it on read only on button click

Tags: wpf, powershell, datagrid, row, selecteditem

It is possible to color a selected row green/red and set it on read only when i press on a button?

I've googled much, but can't really find anything.

One example:

[My Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ksAq.jpg)

When I click on "Software install", the SelectedRow should be colored green and set on readonly.
When I click on "Software uninstall" the SelectedRow should be colored red and set on readonly.

My DataGrid:

```
<Grid
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Grid Background="CornFlowerBlue" Margin="10,10,10,0">
    <DataGrid SelectionMode="single"  Height="250" Name="DataGrid_Applis"  ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Margin="2,2,2,2" ColumnWidth="*">
        <DataGrid.Columns>                      
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Install Status" Binding="{Binding Install_Status}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Version" Binding="{Binding Version}"/>                          
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Updates" Binding="{Binding UpdatesAvailable}"/>                                                                 
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: How is your binding implemented? Do you use (powershell) button events in code behinde or events in xml?

Comment: im using powershell button events in code.